# Using ajax to change the state of a button in Ruby on Rails views

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a setting in which I would like to dynamically change a buttons disabled state. Currently the logic I have looks as follows:

```rb
<% if @has_attachment_file_sent %>
   <% if current_user.id != @offer.user_id %>                     
      <%= link_to send_signature_requests_path, remote: true, method: :post,
          data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" },
          id: "signature_request_button",
          class: "button is-info is-fullwidth  m-t-10 m-b-10"  do %>
          <span>Send request</span>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% else %>
   <button class="button is-info is-fullwidth  m-t-10 m-b-10" disabled>Send request</button>
<% end %>
```

However, the problem with this method is that this only changes the state of the button when you refresh the page. Is there a way to do this kind of Ajax with RoR or what should I do here?

Also tried using javascript as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var has_attachment_file_sent = <%= @has_attachment_file_sent %>
        console.log(has_attachment_file_sent);
        if(has_attachment_file_sent) {
           $('#signature_request_button').attr('disabled', true);
        }        
    })
</script>
```

but this doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Also here's my controller

```
def show
    @offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
    @has_attachment_file_sent = Comment.where(user_id: @offer.user_id).any? {|obj| obj.attachment_file.attached?}
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js { render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript' }
    end
end
```

Comment: when you send a request, you wont to disable the button in if statement and enable the button in the else statement ? or what ?

Comment: @has_attachment_file_sent is a boolean depending on if there's a file uploaded. Based on this I want to update the button.

Comment: how you check if there's a file uploaded?

Comment: @Taoufik Added the controller.

Comment: I have a solution, if you accept I can post  it, to do the ajax call we can associate it with a button, after that we can refresh the state of the button.

Comment: Sounds good! Could you post it?

Answer (score 1):

First place your html in a partial and wrap the content in div, assume that the partial's name is 'buttons.html.erb'

_buttons.html.erb

```
<% if @has_attachment_file_sent %>
   <% if current_user.id != @offer.user_id %>                     
      <%= link_to send_signature_requests_path, remote: true, method: :post,
          data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" },
          id: "signature_request_button",
          class: "button is-info is-fullwidth  m-t-10 m-b-10"  do %>
          <span>Send request</span>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% else %>
   <button class="button is-info is-fullwidth  m-t-10 m-b-10" disabled>Send request</button>
<% end %>
```

```
<div id="buttons">
  <%= render partial: 'buttons' %>
</div>
```

Add button in view

```
<%= link_to 'Refresh', show_page_path(id: @offer.id), id: 'btn_call_ajax', remote: true %>
```

you should adapt show_page_path with your route

```
def show
    @offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
    @has_attachment_file_sent = Comment.where(user_id: @offer.user_id).any? {|obj| obj.attachment_file.attached?}
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
    end
end
```

Then you should create a file named show.js.erb that contain the following code:

```
$('#buttons').html('')
$('#buttons').append("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'buttons') %>");
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's the idea with the "Refresh" link?

Comment: this is a button you can custom the css to look like a button

Comment: But what's the functionality of it?

Comment: it do the ajax call with remote: true

Answer (score 1):

Oh yeah, how annoying, forgot about that

Maybe something like this inside `js.erb`

It should work, hacks but I’m sure there is another solution I’m going blank on

```
# render partial line here
<% if @disabled %>
  $(‘#button-id’).prop(“disabled”, true);
<% else %>

$(‘#button-id’).removeAttr(“disabled”)

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

create the file `show.js.erb` and in your controller just leave it as `format.js` without curly braces.

create a partial with

```
<button class="button is-info is-fullwidth  m-t-10 m-b-10" disabled="<%= disabled ? “disabled” : “”  %>”>Send request</button>
```

And add a div in original file, wrap rendering of the partial above

```
<div id=“woohoo”>
<%= render partial: “file_above”, locals: {disabled: true} %>
</div>
```

Then in that `.js.erb` file add this `$(‘#div-around-button’).html(“<%= j render(‘show’, disabled: @disabled_variable_from_controller) %>”)` and it will basically refresh that button with new value that you got from controller

P.S. I wrote this all on my iPhone so I might have missed small things like syntax

Comment: Hmm, oddly the button seems to be disabled now all the time?

Comment: I'm not sure that the disabled attribute will accept any parameters https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp

Comment: maybe create that button via rails ```<%= button_tag 'Reset', type: 'reset', disabled: @disabled_vadiable %>```

Comment: The button_tag works, but I still need to refresh the page in order for it to take effect

Comment: I know it’s really close, just not near a computer right now :/

Comment: Maybe remote:true on the button? Sorry I have failed you!